# C++: Conceptual circular include problem

Tags: c++, include, circular-dependency

I'm making a component based entity system for a game engine.

I have an entity class, which has to include the component base class header in order to define the array of components `private Component* components[ 123 ]`

However, in the component base class I have to define a `private Entity* ownerEntity`, beacuse it is crucial that a component knows who it belongs to!

This results in Entity.h needing Component.h and vice-versa -> Circular reference

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As long as you only need your class to contain *pointers* or *references* to the other classes, you can skip the real include file and use an empty forward declaration like `class Component;`.

You will need the full include in the source file where you dereference the pointers or use the reference to call methods on `Component`.

Comment: In fact, because in both classes you only need pointers, you can (should!) forward-declare the dependents rather than include them in both headers. Neither of the headers in this case should depend on the other; this will make for a super-fast compile time. Rinse and repeat for all other references, pointers and their const counterparts for each and every class. **Also**: read [what Herb Sutter has to say about compile-time dependencies](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/007.htm).

Comment: You can take the idea too far -- I once "cleverly" forward declared auto_ptr<T> so I could have a very low-level class include a rarely-used toString() method returning auto_ptr<char>.  This means you need `#include <memory>` wherever you *do* call it, and the errors you get from gcc if you don't are hardly intuitive.

Comment: but you should always strive to forward-declare everything you can, rather than `#include` a whole Jurassic Park into your header. If you check that everything compiles, and if you first try to fix what doesn't compile by making changes for supporting forward-declares rather than `#include`, then you're doing well. Aggressively minimizing `#include`s is a Good Practice. It is. Just like any other decoupling.